# undefined data in response

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fetch which returns a JSON when clicked on a Button.

```
$("#search").click(function(event){
    var e = document.getElementById("lineDesc");
    var line = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var month = document.getElementById("descMonth").value;
    var desc = $("#lineDescAr").val();
    var search = document.getElementById("searchtab");
    let fd = new FormData();
        fd.set('line', line);
        fd.set('month', month);
        fd.set('desc', desc);

    fetch('search.php',{method:'POST',body: fd})
        .then( r=> {r.json(); console.log(r);})
        .then( json=>{ //undefined even though response is json
            search.innerHTML="";
            Object.keys( json ).forEach( key=>{
            let obj=json[ key ];
            //search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell">'+/*line*/+'</div>';
            //search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell">'+/*scanner*/+'</div>';
            //search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell">'+/*fault*/+'</div>';
            //search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell">'+/*duration*/+'</div>';
            //search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell">'+/*date*/+'</div>';
            })
        })
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

When i run it, the `.then(json=>` is empty.

In the networkanalysis the response looks like this.

```
[{"line":"L411A","scanner":"Gesamt","fault":"elektrisch","description":"L411A-Test","duration":"100","date":"2021-08-17 07:09:27"}]
```

So it is not empty but the json is?

Appreciate any help.

Would also appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to properly access the returned data.

Comment: Your response is in `r`, then you use `json` which is not defined anywhere. Just keep using `r`, I think (not 'json').

Comment: if you use `r=> {r.json(); console.log(r);}` then you explicitly must add a `return` statement - ie : `r=> { return r.json(); }` ~ without the curly brace you do not need the `return` statement - that is implied

Comment: I think I'm on the right track but check out the professor's comment. I'm not very familiar with the fetch syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first then did not returned any thing so the second get undefined as argument

```
$("#search").click(function(event){
    var e = document.getElementById("lineDesc");
    var line = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var month = document.getElementById("descMonth").value;
    var desc = $("#lineDescAr").val();
    var search = document.getElementById("searchtab");
    let fd = new FormData();
        fd.set('line', line);
        fd.set('month', month);
        fd.set('desc', desc);

    fetch('search.php',{method:'POST',body: fd})
        .then( r=> r.json() )
        .then( json=>{ //undefined even though response is json
            search.innerHTML="";
            Object.keys( json ).forEach( key=>{
            let obj=json[ key ];
            //search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell">'+/*line*/+'</div>';
            //search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell">'+/*scanner*/+'</div>';
            //search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell">'+/*fault*/+'</div>';
            //search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell">'+/*duration*/+'</div>';
            //search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell">'+/*date*/+'</div>';
            })
        })
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: btw here I use this syntaxe ``` r => r.json()``` that mean this function return what is after the arrow but if you want more logic you can use the return operator like in classical function ```r =>  {const x = r.json(); console.log(x); return x;}```

Comment: thank you for the answer I didn't know the curly brackets stopped the return of r.